# Rmathbr doesn't work with \coloneqq

Tags: math-mode, empheq

I was creating one complex tikz-flow chain. One moment compiler stopped working. I was trying to get why.

And I found that the following MWE causes that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}                                           
\usepackage{rmathbr}
\begin{document}
$  b\coloneqq b - F $ 
\end{document}
```

(`\coloneqq` is getting from `empheq` in addition)

I am not expert in LaTeX so it's difficult for me to find the reason of incompatibility of them in the code of packages. But I really need both of them in my work.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is an error (catcode) caused by `rmathbr`. Without the package it works.

Comment: @TeXnician yes, that's the question :)

Comment: It was just to reassure that you also have the catcode error (there is another one when loading the packages in other order).

Comment: @TeXnician for me the strangest thing that if I load `tikz` compiler says that I forgot { }-brackets. and some ways to write `:=` don't work also. I tried `\mathrel{\mathop:}=`

Comment: Btw empheq us not relevant here, mathtools is (it is autoloaded by empheq)

Comment: @daleif yes, I know that dependency...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rmathbr` package is quite invasive and it's not surprising it doesn't behave with other packages.

Here's a fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

% fix \ordinarycolon and define \ordinaryequals
\edef\ordinarycolon{\mathchar\the\mathcode`: }
\edef\ordinaryequals{\mathchar\the\mathcode`= }

\usepackage{rmathbr}
% don't change the category code of ^ here!
\catcode`^=7

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % do the category code change later
  \catcode`^=12
  % fix \coloneqq to be a mathrel also for rmathbr
  \def\coloneqq{%
    \mathrel{{\mathop\ordinarycolon}\mkern-1.2mu{\ordinaryequals}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

$b\coloneqq b - F$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. I hope, in future I will have time to read some books, material in order to become true LaTeXpert.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Probably so. Fixed.